# What is the domain of this random variable?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, self-learning

I've been self-studying *Introduction to Statistical Learning*. From page 16 of the book:

> "...suppose that we observe a quantitative response $Y$ and $p$ different predictors, $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$, $X_p$. We assume that there is some relationship between $Y$ and $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_p)$, which can be written in the very general form $Y = f(X) + \epsilon$

Later on, we analyze the approximation function

$$
\hat{Y} = \hat{f}(X).
$$

**Question 1:** What is the domain of $Y$ and $\hat{Y}$? Is it tuples of *observations* or tuples filled with values from the domains of the $X_1$, $\ldots$, $X_p$?

**Question 2:** Throughout this text, one will see references to the notation like $\hat{f}(x_i)$. For example:

$$
MSE = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{f}(x_i))^2
$$

Isn't the domain of $\hat{f}$ *random variables* (not tuples of *observations* $x_i$)?. If so, isn't this an abuse of notation? Shouldn't we instead (technically) write something like

$$
(f(X_1, \ldots, X_p))(x_i)?
$$

**NOTE:** In case not clear, I mean to use the term "domain" in the purely mathematical sense: i.e., if $f: A \rightarrow B$, then $A$ is the domain (at least how I'm using the term).

Answer (score 1):

So when you are given a sample of response variables Y and some predictor variables $X_1, ... , X_p$, I think you are asked to find the regression between Y and $X_1, ... , X_p$. On the very basics, we use simple linear regression $Y = a_0 + a_1X_1 + ... + a_pX_p + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is the noise(error) term.

Q1.
The domain of Y should just be the population where you sampled your response variable Y. It can be either categorical or numerical

Q2.

$\hat{f}(x_i)$ means our regression estimate on variable $x_i$ where $x_i$ is consisted of p components $x_{i1},x_{i2}, .. x_{ip}$.

For example, we want to predict the height of student. And we have our predictor variables like weight, age, gender, race,..etc. Then $x_i$ is our measure of the ith student of his/her weight, age, gender, race,..etc